# How to declare an object as a parameter to update a userform?

Tags: vba, function, object, methods, parameters

I have a userform which contain checkboxes and labels.

My goal is to enable or disable specific labels if checkboxes are true or false.

I have:

- a module in which I store my functions and subs
- a main module
- the userform

I could write in the userform:

```vb
Private Sub Checkbox1 ()
   If Userform.Checbox1 = true then 
      Userform.label.enable = true 
   End if
```

However I have a few checkboxes and labels and I'd like to create a sub or function to simplify my code.

In the module in which I store my function I wrote:

```vb
Sub EnableMyLabels(Checkbox as object , Label as object) 
    If Userform.Checkbox = true then
        Userform.label.enable = true
    End If
```

and in my userform I tried to use it like this:

```vb
Call EnableMyLabels (Checkbox1 , Label1)
```

Comment: Try using Userform.label.visible = true (or false).

Comment: I think you have to add the name of module where that function resides, something like this `Call Module1.EnableMyLabels (Checkbox1, label1)`

Comment: Thank you for your ansewers, 

@Charlie, my other functions or sub are working fine without adding the name of the module, 
I tried anyway : Module1.EnableMyLabels (Checkbox1, label1) but as i thought it didn't work
i get an error "13"

tlemaster usualy the method enable works fin with labels why wouldn't it work in this case ? 

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should try the same principle but using Events. 
On your VBE, at the Userform module select "Checkbox1" on the top dropdown. 
Then select the method "Click" on the right top dropdown.

A method called Checkbox1_Click should have been created. 
That code will run whenever the user clicks the checkbox. 
**Include all your "label logic" (or logic for other controls too) there.**

Answer (score 0):

Your Sub should be like

```vb
Sub EnableMyLabels(cb As MSForms.CheckBox, lbl As MSForms.Label)
    If cb.Value = True Then
        lbl.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And the call

```vb
EnableMyLabels Checkbox1, Label1
```

You might want to call it from an Event on the Checkbox, eg

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    EnableMyLabels CheckBox1, Label1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it finaly works,
However i don't understand why, 
Why is it necessary to specidy Msform and not object ? 
And why should'nt i specify from which userform it comes : 

"Sub EnableMyLabels(cb As MSForms.CheckBox, lbl As MSForms.Label)
    If UserForm.cb.Value = True Then
        UserForm.lbl.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub"

?

Answer (score 0):

When you are directly passing the objects (passed byRef by default), then there is no need of the `Userform` word in your code. Simply drop that and your code should work perfectly.

```
Sub EnableMyLabels(Checkbox as object , Label as object) 
    If Checkbox = true then
       label.Enabled = true 'fyi - Enabled not Enable
    End If 
End if
```

Comment: Hum ok i think i get it, 
I don't need it since when i specify the parameter VBA knows where it is ? 

Anyway, the code works :D

Comment: Yup. But if you insist on using the Userform name, in that case just make sure to select the exact labels, checkboxes...from the intellisense drop down. `[Eg: Userform1.label1.enabled = True]` Hope that has worked. If so, please mark the answer as accepted.